# Code to merge files in subdirectories not producing expected result using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, merge

The short python code below is intended to merge a series of files (GIS files) which are contained in a series of subfolders.

```
import arcpy
import sys 
import os

PointsMerged = r"C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\MergeOutput\MergedPoints"    ## Provide name and path of the merged feature class


pointslist = []

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    try:
        SrcPath = r"C:\GIS\Test_Workspace"  ## Provide the path for data with subfolder here
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SrcPath, topdown=True):
            for filename in files:

                # check if 'Test' name exists in shapefile name
                if filename.find("Test") == 0:
                        print os.path.join(root, filename)
                        points = str(os.path.join(root, filename))
                        pointslist.append(points)

        arcpy.Merge_management(pointslist, PointsMerged)

    except Exception, ErrorDesc:
        #If an error set output boolean parameter "Error" to True.
        arcpy.AddError(str(ErrorDesc))    
        row = None
        rows = None
```

Below is the result of running the script. As far as I can tell the script runs up to the print function, resulting in a list of all files found in the specificied workspace (directory).

```
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.dbf
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.prj
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.sbn
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.sbx
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.shp
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.shp.xml
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.shx
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.dbf
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.prj
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.sbn
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.sbx
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.shp
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.shp.xml
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.shx
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_Points_2.dbf
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_Points_2.sbn
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_Points_2.sbx
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_Points_2.shp
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_Points_2.shp.xml
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_Points_2.shx
```

Can anyone see why the merge may be failing?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure `arcpy.Merge_management` isn't failing because you are giving it files that it can't process.   You need to filter just the shape files out first

```
import arcpy
import sys 
import os

PointsMerged = r"C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\MergeOutput\MergedPoints"    ## Provide name and path of the merged feature class

pointslist = []

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    try:
        SrcPath = r"C:\GIS\Test_Workspace"  ## Provide the path for data with subfolder here
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SrcPath, topdown=True):
            for filename in files:
                # check if 'Test' name exists in shapefile name
                if filename.endswith(".shp") and "Test" in os.path.basename(filename):
                    fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                    print fullpath
                    pointslist.append(fullpath)

        arcpy.Merge_management(pointslist, PointsMerged)

    except Exception, ErrorDesc:
        #If an error set output boolean parameter "Error" to True.
        arcpy.AddError(str(ErrorDesc))    
        row = None
        rows = None
```

This should yield:

```
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test_Points.shp
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_PointsCopy.shp
C:\GIS\Test_Workspace\Test Sub\Test_Points_2.shp
```

**Note:** I also used `"Test" in os.path.basename(filename)` because that will check only the filename for the word Test, if you don't care about that you can use `"Test" in filename` to just check anywhere in the whole path.